# Use Civicrm with Callhub

Tags: custom-fields, api, civicampaign, phone

I would like to use Civicrm in phone banking. I have managed to link Callhub and Civi together so that a phone call is recorded against a user's name. You can also record some of the call information in the notes field in Civi. However, there does not seem to be any scope for custom fields. For example, I would like to ask people if they have an email address and then record that in Civi. All this information is recorded in discreet fields in Callhub, but to place it in Civi requires exporting and importing a CSV file. Is there an easier way or perhaps a phone banking application that is better than Callhub?

Comment: Are you using https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-extension-for-callhub-phonebanks